# return only column name values from mysql table

Tags: mysql

sorry but i didn't knew how to explain the question in on sentence...
actually i have code like this when i do mysql_fetch_array...

```
        [0] => 10
        [id] => 10
        [1] => 58393
        [iid] => 58393
        [2] => 0
        [ilocationid] => 0
        [3] => 38389
        [iapptid] => 38389
        [4] => 2012-06-30T00:00:00
        [ddate] => 2012-06-30T00:00:00
        [5] => 1000
        [ctimeofday] => 1000
```

but i want to return something like this

```
    [id] => 10
    [iid] => 58393
    [ilocationid] => 0
    [iapptid] => 38389
    [ddate] => 2012-06-30T00:00:00
    [ctimeofday] => 1000
```

i mean without the numeric representatives of the columns. how do i do it...please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the manual for PHP's [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) function:

> The type of returned array depends on how ***`result_type`*** is defined. By using **`MYSQL_BOTH`** (default), you'll get an array with both associative and number indices. Using **`MYSQL_ASSOC`**, you only get associative indices (as [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) works), using **`MYSQL_NUM`**, you only get number indices (as [`mysql_fetch_row()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) works).

Therefore, you want either:

```
mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

or

```
mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Note however the warning:

> Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also [MySQL: choosing an API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) guide and [related FAQ](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more information.  Alternatives to this function include:
>
> - [`mysqli_fetch_array()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)
> - [`PDOStatement::fetch()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Comment: ^^ Will take care of you... =)

Comment: ok so mysql_fetch_assoc workis for this....never tried....and thanks for the warning....i know mysql is discouraged....will get into PDO in some time.....